# Divert Traffic for 1 micro-service on basis of app version using nginx Ingress controller in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing, amazon-eks

I have micro service architecture in GKE. I have a service name socket-service in kubernetes. I have an android app which is the frontend and an Nginx ingress controller and Http application load balancer. I want to create a new socket-service with some new code but I want to divert traffic on basis of android app version. Like for app version 3.1 I want to use old socket-service and for version 3.2 I want to use new socket-service.
I have created layer 7 LoadBalancer as suggested in this: [Global load balancer (HTTPS Loadbalancer) in front of GKE Nginx Ingress Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72476714/global-load-balancer-https-loadbalancer-in-front-of-gke-nginx-ingress-controll)

Answer (score 0):

Nginx supports traffic splitting based on headers https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-service-mesh/tutorials/trafficsplit-deployments/

What you have to do is make the frontend app send a header to the backend to tell it which version. And than you can configure a policy in Nginx to split the traffic based on the value of the header